# Как провести преобразование дубликатов в массиве объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов.

```
let data = [
  {
    "title": "lorem",
    "id": "230",
    "value": "10.4"
  },
  {
    "title": "text1",
    "id": "130",
    "value": "3.9"
  },
  {
    "title": "ipsum",
    "id": "230",
    "value": "5.1"
  },
  {
    "title": "text2",
    "id": "130",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "title": "random text",
    "id": "370",
    "value": "1"
  }
]
```

Нужно пройтись по массиву объектов, найти одинаковые значения по ключу `id`, после чего создать новый объект, в котором ключ-значение `id` не изменится, а все остальные значение будут сложены.

Чтобы на выходе получился вот такой результат:

```
[
  {
    "title": "lorem ipsum",
    "id": "230",
    "value": "15.5"
  },
  {
    "title": "text1 text2",
    "id": "130",
    "value": "8.9"
  },
  {
    "title": "random text",
    "id": "370",
    "value": "1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так (если нужны пояснения - пишите в комментариях):

```js
let data = [{
    "title": "lorem",
    "id": "230",
    "value": "10.4"
  },
  {
    "title": "text1",
    "id": "130",
    "value": "3.9"
  },
  {
    "title": "ipsum",
    "id": "230",
    "value": "5.1"
  },
  {
    "title": "text2",
    "id": "130",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "title": "random text",
    "id": "370",
    "value": "1"
  }
];
var deleted = [];
var length = data.length;

var newData = data.reduce(function(acc, item, idx) {
  if (deleted.indexOf(idx) !== -1) {
    return acc;
  }
  var index = idx + 1;
  while (index < length) {
    var element = data[index];
    if (deleted.indexOf(index) === -1) {

      if (item.id === element.id) {
        item.title = [item.title, element.title].join(' ');
        item.value = (parseFloat(item.value) + parseFloat(element.value)).toString();
        deleted.push(index);
      }
    }
    index++;
  }
  acc.push(item);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData);
```